# Chrome extension that can replaces words **even for popups**?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I wanted to ask, how can I code a chrome extension that will replace certain words in a webpage- **including those in popups**?

For example, most websites have a "this site uses cookies" pop-up or modal. I would like words in that message to be changed as well.

Currently, I am using:

```js
var elementsInsideBody = [...document.body.getElementsByTagName('*')];

function findAndReplace() {
  elementsInsideBody.forEach(element => {
    element.childNodes.forEach(child => {
      // my code to change certain words
    });
  });
}
```

This does replace the required words in the webpage, but not in the cookie-modal or othe pop-ups.

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: Modify your content script's `matches` to include the URLs of those popups. You can find the URL by right-clicking inside the popup or using `chrome://inspect` page.

Comment: Thanks! I I will try that out! But does that mean that my extension will only work for the popups on that particular page? So I have to add every url for every pop up for every site i am ever planning to visit in the marched area?

Comment: You can match all urls with `"<all_urls>"`

Comment: Ok will try it out, thanks!!